# Can not import pygame in Jupyter notebook even though it is installed correctly

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, path, pygame

I want to install pygame on my MacBook. I installed it with the command

```
pip install -U pygame --user
```

However, whenever I ran `import pygame`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError`. I get the same error whether I ran it inside a Jupyter notebook or from the terminal.

```
>>> import pygame
===== 2021.11.03 13:11:29 =====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I uninstalled and re-installed it with different commands:

```
pip install -U pygame
```

```
pip3 install -U pygame --user
```

```
pip3 install -U pygame
```

I checked it is installed correctly by checking `pip freeze` and I ran the command `python3 -m pygame.tests` to check it works well and it does. I added it to the system path as you can see below. The pygame folder is in the site-packages folder.

```
(base) aelashry@Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro asn5 % echo $PATH
/Users/----/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages:/Users/----/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/----/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/----/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

I also restarted my computer. Nothing works. Any body can help?

**Edit**

Thanks to @Matiiss comments, I managed to import the module by running `python3` in the terminal and then `import pygame`. However, it is tsill not working on Jupyter even though the kernel in the notebook is Python 3.

Comment: Show error message

Comment: It's the usual ModuleNotFoundError. I added it anyway.

Comment: are you importing it in the same environment where you installed it?

Comment: @Matiiss, Yes, I didn't create any virtual environment before.

Comment: well, the issue seems very environment related since you can run `pygame.tests` from the console but can't `import pygame`, are you using the same version as where you installed `pygame`

Comment: @Matiiss sorry, I didn't understand. What do you mean I use the same version as where I installed `pygame` ?

Comment: same python version

Comment: @Rabbid76 Where are the screenshots of the code? These are outputs and you don't need to copy any of them.

Comment: @AhmedElashry that is not exactly the only reason as to why screenshots are discouraged, for example they can't really be searched if one has a similar issue

Comment: @Matiiss, I tried to run `python3` in the terminal and I managed to import the module. However, it is still not working on Jupyter even though the kernel is Python 3. 

For the screenshots, you're right. I will edit the question.

Comment: @AhmedElashry unfortunately I can't answer questions about Jupyter, you may need to ask a specific question (rephrase) about `pygame` not working on `Jupyter` perhaps or search if such question has already been answered

Comment: @Matiiss Ok, I will edit my question and search again for an answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, you are right. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out that I had to use `python -m pip install -U pygame` instead of `pip install pygame` so that Jupyter can find the module. I honestly do not know what is the difference, so maybe somebody can elaborate, but that's the solution for my problem.